# Even if the first command in if is true it doesn't print what i want , it only print the else command

Tags: python

```
numberchk=(int(input("Enter a Roman numeral or a Decimal numeral:" )))
def int2roman(number):
    numerals={1:"I", 4:"IV", 5:"V", 9: "IX", 10:"X", 40:"XL", 50:"L",
              90:"XC", 100:"C", 400:"CD", 500:"D", 900:"CM", 1000:"M"}
    result=""
    for value, numeral in sorted(numerals.items(), reverse=True):
        while number >= value:
            result += numeral
            number -= value
    return result
if numberchk==int:
    print(int2roman(int(numberchk)))

else:
    print("error")
```

Comment: Because `numberchk==int` is always False.

Comment: Please indent your code and paste it with the correct code markdown.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try using [isdigit()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit) function.

replace this part on your code

```
if numberchk==int:
```

with

```
if numberchk.isdigit():
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `isinstance(numberchk, int)` instead, because `int` is a type but `numberchk` is an instance of that type.

Since `int(input(...` always returns an integer as long as it can, you don't have to check it using if-else. To suppress error raising if input is not an integer, use `try-except` as @poke mentioned.

You can also use a `while-loop` and `break` to request the user input repeatedly until you get an legal input:

```
while True:
    try:
        numberchk=int(input("Enter a Roman numeral or a Decimal numeral:" ))
        break
    except ValueError:
        print('error')
print(int2roman(numberchk))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if numberchk==int:
```

This will check if `numberchk` is *equal* to the `int` **type**. It will *not* check if `numberchk` is an integer (which you probably want to do). The correct way to check its type would be this:

```
if isinstance(numberchk, int):
```

However, this won’t make sense either. The way you get `numberchk` is by calling `int()` on a string:

```
numberchk=int(input(…))
```

So `numberchk` will *always* be an int. However, calling `int()` on a string that is not a number can fail, so you probably want to catch that error to find out whether or not the input was a number:

```
try:
    numberchk = int(input("Enter a Roman numeral or a Decimal numeral:"))
except ValueError:
    print('Entered value was not a number')
```

But this will again will be problematic, as—at least judging by the message you’re printing—you also want to accept Roman numerals, which can’t be converted to integers by `int`. So you should also write a function that takes a Roman numeral and converts it into an int.

Answer (score -1):

Check the integer type instead of matching variable with `int`.

You can check type of variable with [`isinstance`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#isinstance) method.